# LSTM ANN prediction output is a multiple factor of testinput with same peaks

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I am new to stackoverflow and python, therefore please correct me if I am wrong. I try to make a sequential LSTM to predict a regression task.
I tried different variations of layers, activation, functions etc. The loss is always small,  but my problem is something else. I trained with a data in a certain range (0.1-0.2) than I use a testdata with a range between (0.1-0.9). The range in the prediction is good since I trained with different values, but the prediction output looks like the testdata divided by a factor and has the same peaks and shape. The simpliest model I used is the following:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(16,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(None,1))
model.add(LSTM(1,activation='sigmoid', return_sequences=True))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae','mse']) 
history=model.fit(train,train, epochs=10, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)
```

My testdata is this

[testdata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk16r.png)

my output of prediction is this:
[predicted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1tqo.png)

Where could my problem lie ?

Comment: You might need to tune the learning rate and other parameters if your model is not converging to what you'd like it to.